# How to extract value from multiple cshtml forms in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have a .cshtml page with two forms on it, they are created with `@using (Html.BeginForm("formnamehere"))`

I also have a controller c# file which is supposed to process the data that is entered in this form, it takes in a `FormCollection` as its input parameter. Each Html form also has a drop down list, and it has a submit button

Depending on which form is used, I have to take different actions in my controller. How do I know which form was used in my controller?

Comment: Can you post some code? You will most likely know by the data which you receive.

Comment: Each form should post back to a different controller method. And you should never use `FormCollection` in MVC - use a model and bind to your model.

Comment: `FormCollection` is rarely used on MVC environment, there are model classes in place to bound into views. Either callback or postback can return form information to controller bound for certain view, use whatever method depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You would have two sperate actions in your controller for the each form

```
Html.BeginForm("controllerName", "ActionName") {}
```